How to unplug heating element connector in tumble dryer
heating element 3H1907SAH in tumble dryer AEG LAVATHERM 6DBK72P.
After removing side panel you see on picture the connector of the heating element. I do not know how to  unplug it.
first plug in the socket :the two orange wires connect to the temperature sensor
second plug in the socket: the other three wires, rose color, connect to the heating resistor.
start editing
after reading the thour for the second  time
by mistake I had edited the answer of someone, sorry for that.
I managed to detach the small metal plate on wich is fixed the connection to make a picture of the bottom of connection.
It is not pulling and wiggling that disconnect the connection.
now I give second picture schowing the beneath of connector where I guess I see what could be a spring tab.
I already tried pulling at the plug and at the same time pressing the the tip of a screwdriver, the tip of which is bent 90 degrees,in the slot, the slot  you see in second picture
Still my question stands: how unplug?
Thank for your answer
I hope this editing will be succesfull
end editing



This will be a two-step process:

Unplug the supply plug

Detach the socket, which is part of the heating element assembly


In this photo, #1 shows where the two components separate. There may be a tab on the smaller plug, or it may just be spring-fit (friction only). Look or feel underneath for a spring tab. Wiggle and pull.
Once you have that removed, squeeze the tabs at #2 (both sides) to allow detachment of the socket from the metal plate. Slide it out to the far side.


There might not be any clips at all holding the smaller, male piece on the right to the larger, female piece on the left - it might just be a friction fit requiring some wiggling to unplug. If you can't see the bottom clearly, or identify what's there by feel, use a mirror to look under for a clip. If none present, it's just friction.
